# Socket.read() thread hanging between JBoss and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, jboss, activemq-classic

Given

- My Java app is a WAR deployed to JBoss (4.0.4GA)
- Publishes and subscribes to an ActiveMQ (5.6.0) instance
- Java app uses Apache Camel (2.10.3) for all integration (producing & consuming) with ActiveMQ
- JBoss and ActiveMQ on their own (CentOS 5.6 Final) quad-core virtual servers, each virtual is on a different physical

I have a thread-hanging issue and am seeing the following in my thread dump:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:632)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.validateResponse(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:146)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(SimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:66)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
$Proxy117.SigmaCruxer(Unknown Source)
com.tms.SigmaClient.SigmaClient.processMessage(SigmaClient.java:46)
com.tms.SigmaClient.SigmaServiceEndpoint.doSigma(SigmaServiceEndpoint.java:29)
com.tms.SigmaClient.SigmaServiceEndpoint.mark(SigmaServiceEndpoint.java:43)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:329)
org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:231)
org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:169)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:104)
org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:74)
org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint.onExchange(ProcessorEndpoint.java:102)
org.apache.camel.impl.ProcessorEndpoint$1.process(ProcessorEndpoint.java:72)
org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:114)
org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:284)
org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:109)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:318)
org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:209)
org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:305)
org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:102)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)
org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:104)
org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:85)
org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:91)
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:560)
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:498)
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1058)
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1050)
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

According to these two artices: ([here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/08/javanetsocketinputstreamsocketread0.html) and [here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/04/javanetsocketinputstreamsocketread0.html)), my JBoss app has a blocking I/O operation on `Socket.read()` that is waiting for a completed response from a downstream service provider (in my case, ActiveMQ). Again, according to these articles, the culprit is one of the following 3 items:

- ActiveMQ is in an unhealthy/unstable state and is responding too slowly, causing my listening/waiting/blocking threads to hang; or
- The ActiveMQ instance itself is fine, but is processing an operation (writing to KahaDB, etc.) that is taking too long to complete, again causing my threads to hang; or
- There are networking issues between my JBoss app (WAR) and my ActiveMQ instance.

I'm trying to figure out which of the three is the case. Is there anything in that thread dump to indicate which one it is? My *understanding* (after reading those articles) is that the *real* hang is the fact that the client-side (blocking) socket has just not received all the bytes it needs to consider the response complete; meaning it hasn't received *any* response from ActiveMQ, or it just hasn't received a full response.

So I ask:

1. Is there a clear indication of which of the 3 scenarios is the case? If so, what/why? If not, what *should* my next step be (I am also the "admin" who set up ActiveMQ so I have full access to it as well as JBoss and the WAR deployed to it).
2. Would upgrading to a newer of JBoss fix this? Perhaps 4.0.4GA is using the "old" (blocking) Java I/O, whereas newer versions might use NIO? Probably a long-shot but can't discredit it just yet.
3. Both articles stress that proper socket-timeout configuration should be implemented which may very well mitigate all of this (although it doesn't address the underlying ActiveMQ unresponsiveness and/or networking issues):

   1. Is this a timeout I would write in my Java code? If so how and with what API? JMS? Some ActiveMQ client-side jar?
   2. Is this a timeout I implement at the OS level? If so I'm not sure how to proceed...
   3. Is this a timeout I implement on the server-side (ActiveMQ)? If so, how?

I think I'm closing in on a solution here, but kind of stuck and having a tough time seeing the forest through the trees. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the stack trace whatever is running camel has already received a message from activemq and that message has been dispatched to the listener in camel (the onMessage call).  Camel has done some logic and is making a SigmaCruxer call, which looks like a web service call.  It is that call that is blocked on the socket read in the stack trace.  What is that web service call attempting to contact and is that alive and responsive?  That doesn't appear to be an activemq endpoint - are you sure that your socket is blocked at activemq?

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with JBoss (and Glassfish), and ActiveMQ, but I've never used Camel before (but am familiar with Mule, which I read is similar).

Your stack trace looks like it's Camel trying to link ActiveMQ (JMS-stuff on bottom of trace) to a web endpoint (HTTP-stuff on top of trace).

I'm a bit confused as to where Camel is running (the CamelContext).  You said that you have two virtual machines, one for JBoss and one for ActiveMQ.  In my case, we run Mule ESB on the machine with our ActiveMQ.  Where is your Camel running?

Your stack trace appears most like Problem #1 from the first post.  It's as if the Camel part cannot "see" the web endpoint.  Check to see that your WAR is deployed correctly, and that your web endpoint (WSDL) is visible from both virtual machines.  Check your endpoints; maybe one is set to localhost or something, which would not allow it to get to another machine.

It's a bit hard to tell if it's an incomplete read or a complete inability to read.  Does any data get through?  It's possible that the Web Server is slowly getting overloaded and cannot keep up with requests (and starves some threads as in your error).  Socket timeouts become important when you have slow responses or many requests; if you can create a test that is simple (fast and with few requests) then you can at least verify that you have basic connectivity.  What data input (test) caused this error?

I'll be happy to try to improve this answer given more input.  (I'm sorry I would've tried commenting on your question but I don't think I have the rep for that yet...)

Comment: Thanks @Seka (+1) - some more info for you. The Camel route is "living" (started) inside a WAR that is deployed to JBoss. The Camel route is serving as the JMS client, and ActiveMQ is the JMS server. This is only happening sporadically, where 99.99% of the publishes/subscribes between Camel and ActiveMQ pass through OK. The problem is, every once in a while (several million messages), I see the `socketRead0` (blocked read) and a Camel thread starts to hang. It's hanging because it's waiting for a full response from ActiveMQ and not getting it.

Comment: Are the messages of variable size?  It would be worth knowing whether it's a large single message, or a large number of concurrent messages, that is causing the hang.  For the former, increasing your socket timeouts would help; for the latter, increasing the number of worker threads might help.  From the stack trace, it looks like the Camel thread is hanging on the Socket (Web) side and not the JMS side, like it's trying to pull data down from the socket and send it to JMS, but is not getting the data (or at least not in time).

Comment: Thanks again @Seka (+1) - this is an application that has 64 consumer threads listening on a queue living on the ActiveMQ instance. As soon as a message is enqueued, one of the 64 consumers will pick it up and start processing it. These are slightly-variable-size messages (they're all a *bit* different in size but are generally the same) and are hundreds of thousands of messages per day; sometimes even more. *Curious:* what makes you think this is hanging on the Web side? Does that mean ActiveMQ (the server)? How would you recommend I start diagnosing? Thanks again!

Comment: What got me suggesting the Web Side is that the thread is hanging in the socket read, as if Camel is creating a connection between some socket endpoint and a JMS queue, and the socket side is not providing data.  However, the more I read about your system it could be that the socket is an internal Camel thing, trying to get data from your WAR and back down to ActiveMQ (or vice versa).

Comment: Does your data originate on the Web?  Like is a web request the thing that is triggering the messages and the processing by the consumer threads?  I'm thinking that maybe a 65th concurrent request is being created, and since your workers would all be busy, that thread could hang (be starved since no consumer thread is processing its request).  If the messages are being triggered by the Web Side, it might be possible to limit the number of concurrent Web connections in JBoss (if it doesn't make sense to have more requests than workers).  Of course it depends on your system and requirements.

Comment: Do you know if your ActiveMQ JMS Queue is ever getting filled up, like near capacity?  You mentioned "as soon as the message is enqueued", which led me to believe that your queue is almost always near empty.  I was thinking that maybe all your workers are busy, and then the JMS queue fills, such that your request itself is never enqueued, causing a forever hanging thread.  I would think that would throw an error on the ActiveMQ side though (Queue full).

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys Just trying to follow-up: Were you able to resolve your problem?